# Can !isdigit be used to check for letters in an int?

Tags: c++, int

I found a function in my notes which says the following:

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

Returns `true` if `c` is a digit.

But when keeps getting an error in eclipse which I can't find.

My code so far:

```
for(;;) {
    if (int !isdigit(int(library[count].tele))) { // if a letter,
        printf("Please enter numbers only.");
        count --;
        Menu();
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

`library[count].tele` is of type `int` (in a structure).

All I want to do is check that no letters are in a telephone number.

Comment: "Keep getting an error in eclipse". You don't go to a doctor and say "I feel pain" and don't tell him what kind of pain, do you? Please add the exact error message.

Comment: An `int` is an `int`, it _can't_ "contain letters". You probably want to check this wherever you're reading the input in the first place.

Comment: Also, an `int` isn't suitable for storing a telephone number, because 1) the telephone number might be too large and 2) it won't preserve any leading zeroes. Consider using a string instead.

Comment: my bad. erorr in the 2nd line:

"Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error
- expected expression"

Comment: thanks for the commoents  i guess ill just change it to char then :)

Comment: How do you initialize or store values in `library[count].tele ` before running `isdigit` on it?

Comment: You cannot store a telephone number in a char,unless your telephone number lies between -128 to 127.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit` expects an `int` argument because in original C one processed character codes as integers in order to have enough range to encode `EOF` as a value that could not occur as a character.

in C++ you'd better wrap it in order to avoid Undefined Behavior for non-ASCII characters, like

```
bool isDigit( char const c )
{
    return !!::isdigit( (unsigned char)c );
}
```

it checks a single character

in order to check a string, you can check each character in turn:

```
bool isDigits( string const& s )
{
    for( char c : s )
    {
        if( !isDigit( c ) ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

this solution relies on an assumption of an ASCII-based encoding, but in practice all encodings that you can encounter as of 2013 are based on ASCII

---

the "bang bang" `!!` avoids a silly-warning with the most used c++ compiler, visual c++. for this purpose it can not be replaced with a cast. except for the silly-warning suppression this explicit conversion is not required: the final effect is the same as the language guarantees for an implicit conversion

Comment: The question is a meaningless one. He is storing a telephone number in an int and using isdigit to avoid letters?

Comment: @user93353: may be it's meaningless, but maybe not. the given code won't compile anyway. so there's no saying what the variable type is

Comment: He is explicitly saying that the variable type is int.

Comment: @user93353: thanks! sorry, i didn't notice. harumph, **meaningless question**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `isdigit` for this. However, you have to apply `isdigit` separately to each character in your input string, and make a decision based on what it returns.

You say that `library[count].tele` is of type `int`. By the time the value is stored in an `int`, it is too late to figure out whether it contained any non-digits (it can't). Therefore the checking has to be performed before the conversion from string to `int`.

Comment: He says `library[count].tele` is an int - so where does the string come from?

Comment: @user93353: That's exactly my point -- by the time it's an `int`, it is too late to figure out whether it contained any non-digits :)

Comment: May be you should add your point to your answer - otherwise your answer makes no sense because the question makes no sense.

Comment: @user93353: Fair point. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The `!isdigit( ch )` will test that `ch` is not a digit character ('0' - '9').  That is not the same as testing for a *letter*, since it will be `true` for all non-digit characters which include more than just letters.

In this case it is likely that `!isdigit( ch )` is in fact exactly what you want, but if you wanted to check for letters specifically you would use `isalpha( ch )`.

If you wanted to check the entire string for valid characters in one go (i.e. without the loop), you could simply use:

```
if( strspn( telehone_num, "0123456789" != strlen(telephone_num) ) 
{ 
    printf("Please enter numbers only.");
    Menu();
}
```

Where telephone_num is a C string (not an int). Of course since you tagged this C++ rather than C there are possibly better solutions possible using std::string.

Beyond that you might consider that there are certain conventions with phone numbers in different regions that you might want to allow.  For example it is common in the UK to separate the area code from the local number by a space e.g.:

```
01225 123456
```

Moreover an international user might express the number as:

```
+44 (0)1225 123456
```

Meaning "if calling from outside the UK, dial the local international call code followed 44 then the area code omitting the leading zero, followed by the subscriber's number".  This much information is hard to convey with just digits.  Unless a machine rather than a human is going to be dialling the number, it is sometimes better to let users enter whatever they like.